# EJB3: Stateless beans: How to timeout all at once

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, jboss5.x, stateless-session-bean

Is it possible to timeout all stateless beans at once? IF possible, how?

Comment: What do you mean by "timeout"? Are you asking "how can I remove all stateless beans from the pool?" or "how can I prevent EJBs from being pooled in the first place" or something else?

Comment: Stateless beans have a function annotated @timeout. I have set these functions to do a specific task every X number of minutes.
What i want is to get all stateless beans to execute their timeout methods at once.

Comment: When you say "at once", do you mean "at the same time"?  Rather than trying to coordinate distinct timers for each beans, can you instead create a single timer that invokes a method on all the individual beans?

Comment: yes, i mean at the same time. :)
I don't want a single timer, but i would like to know whether that is possible as well.
What i want is a method that invokes all the timeout functions at the same time.
:)

Comment: The obvious answer seems to be to use TimerService to create timers with a Date. What have you tried so far, and why didn't it work?

Comment: At the moment, i have them all firing the @timeout annotated function every X minutes. Your date suggestion is something interesting to think about. Do  you think it is possible to get the @ timeout annotated function on all beans to fire on one event, such as a button click? sorry, if i sound like a broken record:)

Comment: No, there is no way to cause an immediate timeout of a prescheduled timer. I think the best choice would be to do the action immediately and then cancel the timer.